# Nodos en ptthon y docker, 5 nodos que hacen suma y un nodo usuario que escoge un nodo al azar y comienza la peticion se suma

Tags: python-3.x, nodos

Soy nuevo en python y en docker pero ya estoy usando nano, para hacer el código de python, lo que debe hacer el código es que un usuario escoge un nodo al azar y envia un número a este, este suma el número que le envio el usuario con el suyo y a su vez le envía el número sumado a sus nodos vecinos en orden y espera que el nodo vecino le regrese ese número sumado para enviárselo al siguiente nodo de la lista, cuando la suma termina el último nodo devuelve esa suma y el nodo al cual se le hizo la petición devuelve esa suma al nodo usuario el cual muestra esa suma en pantalla el código que estoy usando funciona en parte pero cuando llega al a un nodo sin vecino y tiene que devolver el número al nodo 1 el cual en este ejemplo le hizo la petición no lo hace se queda y no se que más poder hacer el código que pondré va a ser del 3 pero básicamente es el mismo código para los 5

```
 #nodo3

import xmlrpc.client
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
import time

# List of neighbors
neighbors = ['http://172.17.0.3:8000']

# Restrict to a particular path
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
with SimpleXMLRPCServer(('172.17.0.5', 8000), requestHandler=RequestHandler) as server:
    server.register_introspection_functions()

    # Function to receive a sum request and propagate the sum to its neighbors
    def add(num, node, selected_node):
        global final_result, done, final_node, nodes_check
        
        if len(nodes_check)==5:
            return final_result

        # Add the received number to its own
        print(nodes_check)
        total = num + 4
        nodes_check.append('http://172.17.0.5:8000')

        # Propagate the sum to its neighbors in order
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            if neighbor not in nodes_check:
                print("visited " + neighbor)
                s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(neighbor)
                print("nodo3" + str(nodes_check))
                return s.add(total, server_address, selected_node)

        # Set the done flag to true and wait for a short time
        done = True
        s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(neighbors[-1])
        time.sleep(1)
        print("end" + str(nodes_check))
        server.shutdown()
        return nodes_check

        # If the final result is not set, this is the root node, so set the result
        if not selected_node:
            final_result = total

        # If this is the selected node, set final_node to

        # If a selected_node was provided, return the final result to the user
        if selected_node and final_result:
            user_node = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(selected_node)
            try:
                result = user_node.add(final_result)
                return result
            except:
                pass

        # Close the server's main loop once the sum is done
        server.shutdown()

        # Return the total
        return total if done else None

    nodes_check = []
    final_result = None

    # Set the done flag to false initially
    done = False

    # Set the final_node flag to False initially
    # final_node = False

    server.register_function(add, 'add')

    # Get the server's address
    server_address = f'http://{server.server_address[0]}:{server.server_address[1]}'

    # Run the server's main loop
    server.serve_forever()
```